# Segmentation fault when using pthreads for dotproduct

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, pthreads, dot-product, faults

Ive been trying to make a dot product program for pthreads and I've been having some difficulties. Im getting a segmentation fault when I try to run the program. I am using c to code it.

I had the program working initially with this code:

```
a = (double*) malloc (THREAD_COUNT* SIZE *  sizeof(double));
b = (double*) malloc (THREAD_COUNT* SIZE *  sizeof(double));

for (i=0; i<SIZE*THREAD_COUNT; i++) {
  a[i]=1;
  b[i]=a[i];
  }

dot.size = SIZE;
dot.a = a;
dot.b = b;
dot.sum=0;

pthread_mutex_init(&mutexsum, NULL);

/* Create threads to perform the dotproduct  */
pthread_attr_init(&attr);
pthread_attr_setdetachstate(&attr, PTHREAD_CREATE_JOINABLE);


gettimeofday (&time_start, NULL);

for(i=0;i<THREAD_COUNT;i++)
  {

   pthread_create(&callThd[i], &attr, dotprod, (void *)i); 
   }

pthread_attr_destroy(&attr);

for(i=0;i<THREAD_COUNT;i++) {
  pthread_join(callThd[i], &status);
  }
```

Then I changed the memory allocation because I didnt want the sum to increase by increasing the thread count.

this is the changed code:

```
a = (double*) malloc ( SIZE *  sizeof(double));
b = (double*) malloc (SIZE *  sizeof(double));

for (i=0; i<SIZE; i++) {
  a[i]=1;
  b[i]=a[i];
  }

dot.size = SIZE;
dot.a = a;
dot.b = b;
dot.sum=0;

pthread_mutex_init(&mutexsum, NULL);

/* Create threads to perform the dotproduct  */
pthread_attr_init(&attr);
pthread_attr_setdetachstate(&attr, PTHREAD_CREATE_JOINABLE);


gettimeofday (&time_start, NULL);

for(i=0;i<THREAD_COUNT;i++)
  {

   pthread_create(&callThd[i], &attr, dotprod, (void *)i);
   }

pthread_attr_destroy(&attr);

for(i=0;i<THREAD_COUNT;i++) {
  pthread_join(callThd[i], &status);
  }
```

This is the entirety of my code:

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/time.h> //gettimeofday()
typedef struct
 {
   double      *a;
   double      *b;
   double     sum;
   int     size;
 } DOTPROD;

/* Define globally accessible variables and a mutex */

typedef struct
{

int secs;
int microsecs;


}TIME;

//TIME * time_diff(struct timeval *, struct timeval *);


#define THREAD_COUNT 20
#define SIZE 100000
   DOTPROD dot;
   pthread_t callThd[THREAD_COUNT];
   pthread_mutex_t mutexsum;






void *dotprod(void *arg)
{

/* Define and use local variables for convenience */

   int i, start, end, reg_size ;
   long offset;
   double partsum, *x, *y;
   offset = (long)arg;

   reg_size = dot.size;
   start = offset*reg_size;
   end   = start + reg_size;
   x = dot.a;
   y= dot.b;     /*                                        
 * Perform the dot product and assign result
 * to the appropriate variable in the structure. 
 * */
   partsum = 0;
   for (i=start; i<end ; i++)
    {
      partsum += (x[i] * y[i]);
    }

/*
 * Lock a mutex prior to updating the value in the shared
 * structure, and unlock it upon updating.
 * */
   pthread_mutex_lock (&mutexsum);
   dot.sum += partsum;
   pthread_mutex_unlock (&mutexsum);

   pthread_exit((void*) 0);
}



int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
long i;
double *a, *b;
void *status;
struct timeval time_start, time_end;

TIME*diff;
pthread_attr_t attr;
/* Assign storage and initialize values */

a = (double*) malloc ( SIZE *  sizeof(double));
b = (double*) malloc (SIZE *  sizeof(double));

for (i=0; i<SIZE; i++) {
  a[i]=1;
  b[i]=a[i];
  }

dot.size = SIZE;
dot.a = a;
dot.b = b;
dot.sum=0;

pthread_mutex_init(&mutexsum, NULL);

/* Create threads to perform the dotproduct  */
pthread_attr_init(&attr);
pthread_attr_setdetachstate(&attr, PTHREAD_CREATE_JOINABLE);
                                                   55,16         58%
 * Perform the dot product and assign result
 * to the appropriate variable in the structure. 
 * */
   partsum = 0;
   for (i=start; i<end ; i++)
    {
      partsum += (x[i] * y[i]);
    }

/*
 * Lock a mutex prior to updating the value in the shared
 * structure, and unlock it upon updating.
 * */
   pthread_mutex_lock (&mutexsum);
   dot.sum += partsum;
   pthread_mutex_unlock (&mutexsum);

   pthread_exit((void*) 0);
}



int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
long i;
double *a, *b;
void *status;
struct timeval time_start, time_end;

TIME*diff;
pthread_attr_t attr;
/* Assign storage and initialize values */

a = (double*) malloc ( SIZE *  sizeof(double));
b = (double*) malloc (SIZE *  sizeof(double));

for (i=0; i<SIZE; i++) {
  a[i]=1;
  b[i]=a[i];
  }

dot.size = SIZE;
dot.a = a;
dot.b = b;
dot.sum=0;

pthread_mutex_init(&mutexsum, NULL);

/* Create threads to perform the dotproduct  */
pthread_attr_init(&attr);
pthread_attr_setdetachstate(&attr, PTHREAD_CREATE_JOINABLE);
                                                   55,16         58%
 * Perform the dot product and assign result
 * to the appropriate variable in the structure. 
 * */
   partsum = 0;
   for (i=start; i<end ; i++)
    {
      partsum += (x[i] * y[i]);
    }

/*
 * Lock a mutex prior to updating the value in the shared
 * structure, and unlock it upon updating.
 * */
   pthread_mutex_lock (&mutexsum);
   dot.sum += partsum;
   pthread_mutex_unlock (&mutexsum);

   pthread_exit((void*) 0);
}



int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
long i;
double *a, *b;
void *status;
struct timeval time_start, time_end;

TIME*diff;
pthread_attr_t attr;
/* Assign storage and initialize values */

a = (double*) malloc ( SIZE *  sizeof(double));
b = (double*) malloc (SIZE *  sizeof(double));

for (i=0; i<SIZE; i++) {
  a[i]=1;
  b[i]=a[i];
  }

dot.size = SIZE;
dot.a = a;
dot.b = b;
dot.sum=0;

pthread_mutex_init(&mutexsum, NULL);

/* Create threads to perform the dotproduct  */
pthread_attr_init(&attr);
pthread_attr_setdetachstate(&attr, PTHREAD_CREATE_JOINABLE);
                                                   55,16         58%
 * Perform the dot product and assign result
 * to the appropriate variable in the structure. 
 * */
   partsum = 0;
   for (i=start; i<end ; i++)
    {
      partsum += (x[i] * y[i]);
    }

/*
 * Lock a mutex prior to updating the value in the shared
 * structure, and unlock it upon updating.
 * */
   pthread_mutex_lock (&mutexsum);
   dot.sum += partsum;
   pthread_mutex_unlock (&mutexsum);

   pthread_exit((void*) 0);
}



int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
long i;
double *a, *b;
void *status;
struct timeval time_start, time_end;

TIME*diff;
pthread_attr_t attr;
/* Assign storage and initialize values */

a = (double*) malloc ( SIZE *  sizeof(double));
b = (double*) malloc (SIZE *  sizeof(double));

for (i=0; i<SIZE; i++) {
  a[i]=1;
  b[i]=a[i];
  }

dot.size = SIZE;
dot.a = a;
dot.b = b;
dot.sum=0;

pthread_mutex_init(&mutexsum, NULL);

/* Create threads to perform the dotproduct  */
pthread_attr_init(&attr);
pthread_attr_setdetachstate(&attr, PTHREAD_CREATE_JOINABLE);
                                                   * Perform the dot product and assign result
 * to the appropriate variable in the structure. 
 * */
   partsum = 0;
   for (i=start; i<end ; i++)
    {
      partsum += (x[i] * y[i]);
    }

/*
 * Lock a mutex prior to updating the value in the shared
 * structure, and unlock it upon updating.
 * */
   pthread_mutex_lock (&mutexsum);
   dot.sum += partsum;
   pthread_mutex_unlock (&mutexsum);

   pthread_exit((void*) 0);
}



int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
long i;
double *a, *b;
void *status;
struct timeval time_start, time_end;

TIME*diff;
pthread_attr_t attr;
/* Assign storage and initialize values */

a = (double*) malloc ( SIZE *  sizeof(double));
b = (double*) malloc (SIZE *  sizeof(double));

for (i=0; i<SIZE; i++) {
  a[i]=1;
  b[i]=a[i];
  }

dot.size = SIZE;
dot.a = a;
dot.b = b;
dot.sum=0;

pthread_mutex_init(&mutexsum, NULL);

/* Create threads to perform the dotproduct  */
pthread_attr_init(&attr);
pthread_attr_setdetachstate(&attr, PTHREAD_CREATE_JOINABLE);

gettimeofday (&time_start, NULL);

for(i=0;i<THREAD_COUNT;i++)
  {

   pthread_create(&callThd[i], &attr, dotprod, (void *)i);
   }

pthread_attr_destroy(&attr);

for(i=0;i<THREAD_COUNT;i++) {
  pthread_join(callThd[i], &status);
  }
/* After joining, print out the results and cleanup */



gettimeofday (&time_end, NULL);


long long elasped = (time_end.tv_sec - time_start.tv_sec)*1000000LL + time_end.tv_usec - time_start.tv_usec;

printf ("time diff in microseconds = %6d \n",elasped);

printf ("Sum =  %f \n", dot.sum);
//diff = time_diff(&time_start, &time_end);

//printf("Time = %d. \%5d.%6d secs. \n", diff->secs, diff -> microsecs);
free (a);
free (b);
pthread_mutex_destroy(&mutexsum);
pthread_exit(NULL);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the initial code, `dot.size` and `SIZE` were the same thing, and the vector size was `SIZE * THREAD_COUNT`. So if you had 4 threads and each thread did 5 multiplies, then the vector size was 20.

In the new code, `SIZE` is now the vector size, and you're trying to divide the work among `THREAD_COUNT` threads. Therefore `dot.size` needs to be `SIZE / THREAD_COUNT`. So if `SIZE` is 20 and `THREAD_COUNT` is 4, then `dot.size` needs to be 20/4 = 5.